# Reference for a characterization of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Answers in these posts

- [Let $X,Y$ be two real valued random variables. What is the joint density of the pair $(X, X)$ and how do we calculate $E[h(X,Y)|X=x]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991939/let-x-y-be-two-real-valued-random-variables-what-is-the-joint-density-of-the?rq=1)
- [Conditional density of Sum of two independent and continuous random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473790/conditional-density-of-sum-of-two-independent-and-continuous-random-variables)

use the following fact:

> reacall that $E(h(X,Y)\mid X)=u(X)$ for some measurable function $u$ if and only if $E(h(X,Y)v(X))=E(u(X)v(X))$ for every bounded measurable function $v$

(Starting from the factorization lemma, which characterizes the conditional expectation a.s.,)
I believe one direction is the a.s.-point-wise approximation of measurable functions together wth the dominated convergence theorem, and the other direction is indicator functions being bounded.

Is this written somewhere? ("Recall" sounds like it is, but I did not know this result and I had to think a bit.)

Comment: This is basically just the definition of conditional expectations plus the factorization lemma, which says that $Z$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable if and only if $Z = v(X)$ for some measurable function $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

($\Rightarrow$). Suppose $E[h(X,Y)|X]=u(X)$ for some measurable $u$. Since $v$ is assumed to be bounded and measurable, then $v(X)$ is integrable and $\sigma(v(X))\subseteq \sigma(X)$ so
$$\begin{aligned}E[h(X,Y)v(X)]&=E[E[h(X,Y)|X]v(X)]=\\
&=E[u(X)v(X)]
\end{aligned}$$
($\Leftarrow$). Let $A\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Choose $v(x)=\mathbf{1}_A(x)$, which is bounded and measurable. Then $\mathbf{1}_A(X(\omega))=\mathbf{1}_{\{X\in A\}}(\omega)$. Recall $\sigma(X)=X^{-1}(\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ so that if $C\in \sigma(X)$ then $C=X^{-1}(A)$ for some Borel $A$. By assumption
$$E[h(X,Y)\mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(A)}]=E[u(X)\mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(A)}],\,\forall A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
but this means $E[h(X,Y)|X]=u(X)$, $P$-a.e.

Comment: Ahh ok I missed this trick>$E[h(X,Y)v(X)]=E[E[h(X,Y)|X]v(X)]$. Thank you! Is written somewhere, I wonder?

Comment: @kist it is a [property of conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) (the 'pulling out the known' coupled with total expectation)

Comment: Sorry I know that but I meant I wonder if the property in the question (what you proved) is written somewhere.

Comment: @kist no I don't think I've ever seen it written explicitly like that (e.g. as a lemma or proposition)

Comment: Ah ok...oh well at least now I know how to show this. Thanks anyway. I have other questions on conditional probability posted so I'd appreciate it if you could have a look!